How to read data from minio using postgresql foreign tables
I have a minio object structure as below:

experiment_1/images/sample1/<thousands of images>

experiment_1/images/sample2/<thousand of images>


I want to create a foreign table to actually query these images. So e.g I should be able to Select From Images where name='abc'.
I am new to Foreign Tables, and was trying to follow the documentation of paradedb to do this, but the docs are all for creating Foreign Tables from csv and parquet files.
Is there a way to do this?
In the past, I used to store the absolute number of image in the tabe, and also the dir_name, for each image. Which would allow me to query an image at a time point (absolute number). But I don't want to store the same information 2 times.

Their doc seems to suggest so: "S3 foreign tables have been tested against the following object stores that implement the S3 API: Amazon S3, MinIO, Cloudflare R2, and Google Cloud.".

@Zegarek Yes, but they read 'files' from S3, not paths. I think I found what I wanted, am testing it, and then will see how it works. https://github.com/pgsql-io/multicorn2
